# Search from all custom-fields very slow. I need filter search for custom post type

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I'm doing a custom search in my WP and in the search field, any typed word will be sought in custom-fields, in the titles and posting content.

It turns out that my database has more than 1 million custom-fields lines, and wanted to limit the search only for a certain type of post.
I already do this in the Loop to display the results, but I wish this filter was made in consultation because the page is taking over 20 seconds to display the result.

Can anyone help me? Below the code I'm using.

```
    // SEARCH FROM ALL CUSTOM FIELDS
    $post_ids_meta = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
    ALTER TABLE wp_posts ADD INDEX (postmeta)
    SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM {$wpdb->postmeta}
    WHERE meta_value LIKE '%s'
    ", $keyword ) );

    // SEARCH FOR TITLE AND CONTENT
    $post_ids_post = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
    ALTER TABLE wp_post s ADD INDEX (posts);
    SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts}
    WHERE post_title LIKE '%s'
    OR post_content LIKE '%s'
    ", $keyword, $keyword ) );
    $post_ids = array_merge( $post_ids_meta, $post_ids_post );
```

Comment: dynamically adding indexes for 1 time use, is not going to help performance. If an index is only used once, there is no benefit of having the index compared to a full table scan (full table scan will be slightly to way faster in that case depending on how much the index helps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATE:

Try this one. It's not tested but I'm sure it will work if you check and fix it a little bit:

```
// SEARCH IN title, content and meta_value
$post_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS p,
    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS m,
    ON m.post_id = p.ID
    WHERE p.post_type = '%s'
    AND (
    post_title LIKE '%%s%'
    OR m.meta_value LIKE '%%s%'
    OR post_content LIKE '%%s%')
", $post_type, $keyword, $keyword, $keyword) );
```

Note:

- Assume you have taken input `$post_type` & `$keyword`. Eg: `$post_type = "fairs";`
- I added % before and after %s to make sure it's widecard search.
- In this case, I use DISTINCT because the joint table have repeated IDs. My apologies for the previous fault assumption on your first query that it was not needed.
- Speed is not guaranteed, since you are doing a widecard search on post_content which is not indexed.
- You should make sure the meta_value field is indexed for a little faster speed. If you meta don't store too much text in it.

GOOD LUCK!

### ORIGINAL:

Firstly, let's clarify these:

1. Remove these 2 lines as it won't help (it make it worse due to repeated call):

   ALTER TABLE wp_posts ADD INDEX (postmeta)

And

```
ALTER TABLE wp_posts ADD INDEX (posts);
```

2. ID is already distinct. So it won't help you do: `SELECT DISTINCT ID`

The **final queries** should look like these:

```
// SEARCH FROM ALL CUSTOM FIELDS
$post_ids_meta = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
SELECT post_id FROM {$wpdb->postmeta}
WHERE meta_value LIKE '%s'
", $keyword ) );

// SEARCH FOR TITLE AND CONTENT
$post_ids_post = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts}
WHERE post_title LIKE '%s'
OR post_content LIKE '%s' // Remove this will boost performance by 90% because post_content is not indexed
", $keyword, $keyword ) );
$post_ids = array_merge( $post_ids_meta, $post_ids_post );
```

What **I recommend** is to use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-everything/

Comment: Hello, thank you for the return and your considerations. Even with the code you suggested, it will make searches on all lines (1 million) and not only the lines that match the post-type = fairs.
Regards

Comment: Hi @QuebrandoCabeca, Ugh, OK. Let me check and update my answer.

Comment: Hi @Binh WPO, First, I appreciate your response. Excuse the delay in return, made changes to the code, but generated an error in SQL follows    WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN imp_postmeta AS m, ON m.post_id = p.ID WHERE p.post_type = 'f' at line 2]
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM imp_posts AS p, INNER JOIN imp_postmeta AS m, ON m.post_id = p.ID WHERE p.post_type = 'feiras' AND ( post_title LIKE '% %' OR m.meta_value LIKE '% %' OR post_content LIKE '% %')

Comment: 3 reasons why indexing `meta_value` is useless:  (1) OR; (2) leading wildcard; (3) If meta_value is `TEXT`, you can't index it.  (No, `INDEX(meta_value(255))` is not useful in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$keyword` has no wildcards, you might try expressing this query as:

```
SELECT ID
FROM {$wpdb->posts}
WHERE post_title LIKE '%s'
UNION
SELECT ID
FROM {$wpdb->posts}
WHERE post_content LIKE '%s';
```

MySQL might figure out to use the indexes for this.  The indexes that you want are:

```
create index wp_post_title_id on wp_post(post_title, id);
create index wp_post_content_id on wp_post(post_content, id);
```

This assumes that`{$wpdb->posts}` is really `wp_post`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the return and your considerations. Even with the code you suggested, it will make searches on all lines (1 million) and not only the lines that match the post-type = fairs.
Regards

Comment: @QuebrandoCabeca . . . That is simply not true.  Each subquery will use use the appropriate index.  The results then need to be combined.